# scikit-learn fails to load

Tags: python, linux, scipy, scikit-learn, atlas

I installed scikit-learn 0.13 with `pip install scikit-learn`.

```
from sklearn import svm, metrics
```

fails with

```
from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
from ..linear_model.base import LinearClassifierMixin
from .base import LinearRegression
from .cd_fast import sparse_std
ImportError: sklearn/linear_model/cd_fast.so: undefined symbol: ATL_dcopy
```

NumPy and SciPy seem without issues (`test()` passes), at versions 1.7.0 and 0.11.0, installed from sources. The latest ATLAS 3.10.1 is installed on the machine, also from sources.

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: What does `numpy.distutils.system_info.get_info('blas_opt', 0)` return?

Answer (score 1):

adding atlas lib for compiling solves the problem.
edit the file sklearn/linear_model/setup.py by adding a line before or after cblas_libs.append('m'):
    cblas_libs.append('atlas')

then rebuild and install scikit-learn